# Holding Alt+O does not repeat

Tags: animation, camera, keyframes

I'm working with prototyping camera movement using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7qyW1G350g) and I'm having trouble holding Alt-O (hotkey for smoothing keyframes) as he did at about 2:54.

When he holds the hotkey, it repeats itself automatically and the camera keyframes are smoothed almost instantly, but when I hold it, it acts like I've only pressed it once. It's a real pain when I have to do it about 50 times manually, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your keymap enabled "repeat"? go to preferences and check it

Comment: @XY Where could one find this “repeat” toggle? I can’t seem to see it in the preferences anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a Key-Binding and set to "Repeat"

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It was already enabled but I just disabled it, closed Blender and enabled it again and it works fine now. Thanks again!